# Use dynamic distribution to store student information input by users and output

Tags: c

I need to use dynamic distribution to store the personal information of students sent by users and print them out, but when I enter more than one student as the target, the system will remind me "stack buffer overflow". How can I modify this code error? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student {
    int age;
    float score;
    char name[100]; };

void input_student (struct Student **in_st, int len); 
void output_student (struct Student **out_st, int len); 
int main(void) {
    struct Student *pArr;
    int length;
    
    printf("How many student you want input\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    
    pArr = malloc(length * sizeof(struct Student));
    
    input_student(&pArr,length);
    output_student(&pArr,length);

}

void input_student (struct Student **in_st, int len) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        printf("Please input the information of %d student\n", i+1);
        printf("age is \n");
        scanf("%d", &in_st[i]->age);
        
        printf("score is \n");
        scanf("%f",&in_st[i]->score);
        
        printf("Name is \n");
        scanf("%s", in_st[i]->name);
        
        i++;
    } }


void output_student (struct Student **out_st, int len) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        printf("%d %f %s\n",out_st[i]->age, out_st[i]->score, out_st[i]->name);
        i++;
    }}
```

Comment: *always reminds me that an error has occurred*. If there is an error it would make sense to show that error. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67117695/edit) your question to update it with that info.

Comment: `pArr = *(struct Student **)malloc(length * sizeof(struct Student*));` That doesn't make sense. `malloc` returns a pointer with uninitialised contents. So it makes no sense to dereference the pointer to get that content. You probably want: `pArr = malloc(length * sizeof(struct Student));`

Comment: Dynamic distribution? Do you mean *dynamic allocation*?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have revised my question, because I encountered a new problem when I was running

Comment: Yes, I think I mean dynamic allocation

Comment: `void input_student (struct Student **in_st, int len)` That's wrong. You don't actually have an array of pointers as defined there. Do this instead `void input_student (struct Student *in_st, int len)` and access with `scanf("%d", &in_st[i].age);` and call with `input_student(pArr,length);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I modified my code according to the method you provided, and it ran successfully!

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)